# How to connect firebase android project to python firebase

Tags: python, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have a python script on my laptop in which I want to push some data continuously to firebase realtime database.Now this was easy but I had to create a web app firebase project for that.
Next I want to retrieve the same data from this web-app firebase database from my flutter app but I think for that I need to create an android firebase project.

So how to send data from my python script to android firebase project?

For python I created a web app project and this was the config I received from firebase:

```
firebaseConfig = {
    "apiKey": "...",
    "authDomain": "...",
    "projectId": "...",
    "storageBucket": "...",
    "messagingSenderId": "...",
    "appId": "...",
    "measurementId": "..."
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)

db = firebase.database()

data = {"key":"value"}
db.push(data)
```

So this was easy but on my flutter app I cannot connect to the same database nor android firebase project provides the same config to connect with python.

So what other options I have or any solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your Python Script that runs on you laptop you should use the "Python Firebase Admin SDK".
It will write to your normal Firebase Database. I have a Python Script running and uploading things to my Fireabse DB and my Android App can read it.